# SQL Query to get the last set of distinct records with some conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to get the records for those customers that have expired, and then update the table accordingly (by update I mean add an a new record with entry 'SERVICE EXPIRED' with the customer_id of the relevant customer).

If you look at the bottom of the table, you will notice two records with the entry 'SERVICE EXPIRED' for already existing customers (customer_id 11 and 16).

I'm looking for a SQL Query that will:

1. Get the last set of distinct records by customer_id
2. Exclude records for the same customer_id from the resulting resultset that have the entry 'SERVICE EXPIRED' or status_id of 2 appearing later on in the table

If I use the following:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable WHERE status_id != '2' AND expiry < '2012-12-26 19:00:00' GROUP BY customer_id
```

It will return ids 1, 11, 13, and 16. However, I don't want ids 11 and 16 because the expiry status has already been noted later on in the table (see the last two records of the table), and id 1 has been renewed as can be seen with an updated expiry date in id 3 later. All I want is id 13 because that is the only expired record that does not have a 'SERVICE EXPIRED' entry that appears later in the table.

I'm looking for a SQL Query that will enable me capture this requirement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: any chance you could create a SQL Fiddle or paste your existing data in a copy-friendly format?  I have a possible answer but I'd like to test it.

Comment: @ExactaBox I've managed to find a way to pulling it off. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling around I managed to come up with a solution:

```
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM mytable
WHERE status_id != '2' 
    AND expiry < '2012-12-26 19:00:00' 
    AND customer_id NOT IN (SELECT MAX(customer_id) FROM mytable WHERE status_id = '2' GROUP BY customer_id) 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Thanks @JupiterP5 for pointing me in the right direction.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It's not efficient, but this should work.

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM mytable
WHERE status_id != '2'
    AND expiry < '2012-12-26 19:00:00'
    AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable where status_id = 2)
GROUP BY customer_id
```

Edit: Missed the service renewed case. I'll update if I think of something.

Comment: Thanks. I used this to get what I need. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is equivalent to finding "n" records after the last expiry on a record.  The following query returns all records after the last expiry for a given customer:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.customer_id, MAX(id) as maxid
      from t
      where status_id = 2
     ) texp
     on t.customer_id = texp.customer_id and
        t.id > texp.maxid
```

By using variables cleverly, you can enumerate these to get the last "n".  However, do you really need a fixed number?  Why not all of them?  Why not just one of them?